# How to extract values inside brackets in a json string using Java Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to use regex to extract the values used inside the second []

```
[
"Shoes for men wither",
"Shoes for men wither leather",
]
```

[image]

I have tried the following: check all the words between quotes.

```
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"").matcher(response);
```

The problem with the above is that it gives me the other values outside the inner array.

Comment: I think it's much easier without regex. You need 1st open bracket and then first closing bracket right after.

Comment: You mean just with String.replace() and without using regex?

Comment: What I said will give you start and end points for `substr() `.

Comment: Correction. 2nd opening bracket.

Comment: The problem is I don't know the index of the second [ ]  as the json output string can vary. it could be [ "abc" [ "def", "ghi"] ], here I want the values "def", "ghi"

Comment: You can use `Pattern.compile("(?:\\G(?!\\A)\\s*,\\s*|^\\s*\\[\\s*\"[^\"]*\"\\s*,\\s*\\[\\s*)\"([^\"]*)\""`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MpLjef/1).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like JSON, which is [not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language), and thus can't be parsed reliably with regex. You would almost certainly be better off using a JSON parsing library, such as [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or one of the many listed at [json.org](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: I agree you are right. How would you put in a Wrapper.java class for this JSON output https://completion.amazon.com/search/complete?search-alias=aps&client=amazon-search-ui&mkt=1&q=iphone

Comment: If you were using Gson, you'd probably want to decode it with [JsonParser.parseString](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html#parseString(java.lang.String)) and call `getAsJsonArray()` on it, and grab the second element of that as a `JsonArray` as well.